# How to create a new column with Grand Total for each item?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Sql Server 2014 and I have a T-SQL query which stands as follows:

```
    Use MyDatabase
     Select Market, Sum([RN]) as [RN]
     From [View1]
     Group by Market
```

Output is as follows:

```
          Market               RN
          UK                      100
          FRANCE             125
          GERMANY          300
```

I need to add a new column to my output as follows:

```
     Market               RN.         Grand Total
     UK                      100        525
     FRANCE             125        525
     GERMANY          300       525
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want window function :

```
select distinct market, 
       sum(rn) over (partition by market) as rn, 
       sum(rn) over () as Total
from view1 v1;
```